# Boost program options detect whether default value was used

Tags: boost

I'm using Boost `program_options` with an argument that has a `->default_value()`. Is there any way to tell whether the value that results was specified by the user on the command line, or by the default value?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a way - `variable_value::defaulted()`:

```
  po::variables_map vm;
  try {
    po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
  } catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << "error parsing command line: " << e.what() << "\n";
    return 1;
  }

  // Needed to set default arguments.
  po::notify(vm);

  if (vm["myparam"].defaulted())
     ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can count inside the parsed options:

```
template <typename Options, typename Option = typename Options::value_type>
bool is_provided(std::string const& key, Options const& within) {
    return 0 != std::count_if(within.begin(), within.end(), [=](Option const& opt) { return opt.string_key == key; });
}
```

Here's a demo with test cases:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c3981910db13c49)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace po = boost::program_options;

template <typename Options, typename Option = typename Options::value_type>
bool is_provided(std::string const& key, Options const& within) {
    return 0 != std::count_if(within.begin(), within.end(), [=](Option const& opt) { return opt.string_key == key; });
}

void run_test(std::vector<char const*> commandline) {
    po::options_description desc;
    desc.add_options()
        ("option,o", po::value<std::string>()->default_value("not_supplied"));

    try {
        commandline.insert(commandline.begin(), "demo.exe");
        int const argc = commandline.size();
        commandline.push_back(nullptr); // standards compliance, not really required here

        po::variables_map vm;
        auto parsed = po::parse_command_line(argc, commandline.data(), desc);
        po::store(parsed, vm);
        po::notify(vm);

        std::cout << (is_provided("option", parsed.options)?"Given":"defaulted") 
                  << " value: " << vm["option"].as<std::string>() << "\n";
    } catch(std::exception const& e) {
        std::cout << "Error: " << e.what() << "\n";
        std::cout << "Usage: " << desc << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    run_test({"--option", "value1"});
    run_test({"--option=value2"});
    run_test({"-o", "value3"});
    run_test({});
    run_test({"--option"});
    run_test({"--bogus"});
}
```

Prints

```
Given value: value1
Given value: value2
Given value: value3
defaulted value: not_supplied
Error: the required argument for option '--option' is missing
Usage:   -o [ --option ] arg (=not_supplied)

Error: unrecognised option '--bogus'
Usage:   -o [ --option ] arg (=not_supplied)
```